# Monads and custom traversal functions in Haskell

Tags: data-structures, haskell, monads

Given the following simple BST definition:

```
data Tree x = Empty | Leaf x | Node x (Tree x) (Tree x)
          deriving (Show, Eq)

inOrder :: Tree x -> [x]
inOrder Empty                  = []
inOrder (Leaf x)               = [x]
inOrder (Node root left right) = inOrder left ++ [root] ++ inOrder right
```

I'd like to write an in-order function that can have side effects.  I achieved that with:

```
inOrderM :: (Show x, Monad m) => (x -> m a) -> Tree x -> m ()
inOrderM f (Empty) = return ()
inOrderM f (Leaf y) = f y >> return ()
inOrderM f (Node root left right) = inOrderM f left >> f root >> inOrderM f right

-- print tree in order to stdout
inOrderM print tree
```

This works fine, but it seems repetitive - the same logic is already present in **inOrder** and my experience with Haskell leads me to believe that I'm probably doing something wrong if I'm writing a similar thing twice.

Is there any way that I can write a single function inOrder that can take either pure or monadic functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `inOrder` you are mapping a `Tree x` to a `[x]`, i. e. you sequentialize your tree. Why not just use `mapM` or `mapM_` on the resulting list?

```
mapM_ print $ inOrder tree
```

Just to remind the types of the functions I've mentioned:

```
mapM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
mapM_ :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()
```

Comment: It might be instructive to realize that mapM_ f is just shorthand for sequence_ . map f -- That is, you *can* apply a function (a -> m b) to each of your inOrder items with plain ol' map. Now you have a list of monadic actions, but they have no order. The function sequence_ then takes them, and essentially applies >> to them in sequence, which gives a monadic action that does them in the order of the list. Of course, the magic of optimization means that that list may very well never actually be built or be in memory all at once!

Comment: mapM is similar but uses sequence, and sequence is the same as sequence_ only it collects the results as it runs the monadic actions and makes that collection the result of compound action.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to look at implementing the `Data.Traversable` class or `Data.Foldable` class for your tree structure.  Each only requires the definition of a single method.

In particular, if you implement the `Data.Foldable` class, you get the following two functions for free:

```
mapM_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m ()
toList :: Foldable t => t a -> [a]
```

It will also give you the rich set of functions (`foldr`, `concatMap`, `any`, ...) that you are used to using with the list type.

You only have to implement one of the following functions to create an instance of `Data.Foldable`:

```
foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```